# Iphone, pickerView controller.

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I tried many ways, but was not successful.
I have to make use of a picker.
First it should have 2 components, secondly One component and finally one component.
there is button,after pressing this button the picker components should change as above. If there is any way please share it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[picker reloadData];
```

use this in your IBAction also use int variable suppose int checker (0 for two component,1 and 1 for 1 component)

the in `IBAction` write code like this

```
checker++;
  if(checker>2)
    checker=0;
   [picker reloadData];
```

and it numberOfComponents datasource method use this checker for making your if else

look like this

```
if(checker>0)
   return 1;
else 
  return 2;
```

remember `checker` must be global type.